# Parsing a Gzip buffer in a Multiplatform (JS/Java + C#) Web platform

Tags: javascript, java, c#, gzip, unzip

Let me explain a bit about my system. I have a third party software that communicates with a library/API (C#) of mine. This library communicates with my FrontEnd (JS) and, of course, this Front End communicates with my BackEnd (Java).

My problem is that I need my library/API to compress an XML that comes from third-party software, I pass it to the FrontEnd and it passes it to the BackEnd. But because this XML is too large, I need the library/API to compress it and the BackEnd unzip it. When the buffer reaches my BackEnd the decompressor jumps a "Not in GZip format" exception. I get the impression that the problem is in the Parse, but I can not find the solution. I would appreciate any help.

Library/API Code (C#):

```
public string operationXML(String xmlIN){
 try
 {
  [...]
  byte[] binaryData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlUtil.ObjectSerializer(objOUT, null)); 
  //xmlUtil.ObjectSerializer returns a XML in String format
  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(CompressGZip(bynaryData));
 }
 catch()[...]
}
public byte[] CompressGZip(byte[] raw){
 using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream()){
  using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress, true)){
   gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
  }
  return memory.ToArray();
 }
}
```

FrontEnd (JS) Calling the library/API and Passing to BackEnd:

```
var response = petition("operationXML", responseObject.responseText);
conn.request({
 url: gContextPath + "/MostradorGrid.json",
 method: 'POST',
 params: {
 "action": "processXML",
 "response": response,
 "idUser": gIdUser
  },
  success: function (responseObject) {[...]
```

BackEnd Controller (Java):

```
case processXML:{
 if (ParamMap.containsKey("idUser") && ParamMap.containsKey("response")) {                      
  int idUser= NumberUtils.toInt(ParamMap.get("idUser")[0]);
  byte[] xmlgzip=  ParamMap.get("response")[0].getBytes("UTF8");
  grid271 grid271 = (grid271) getWebApplicationContext().getBean("grid271");
  response.getWriter().println(grid271.xmlprocess(xmlgzip, idUser));
 }
}
```

BackEnd grid271.xmlprocess

```
[...]
byte[] temp = compressor.dGzip(xmlgzip);
String data= compressor.bytesToString( temp , "UTF_8", true);
[...]
```

BackEnd compressor

```
public byte[] dGzip(byte[] contentBytes) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes)), out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

In IOUtils.copy(new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes)), out); is when the Exception jumps: (java.Util.zip.zipException) java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should first identify the erroneous part. Save the library output to a file and use command line gzip to decompress. If it is ok, then let your Java part decompress the file. And to verify your JS code you should check, if the library output is the same as the Java input after the call.

Comment: Ok, I'm on it. thx.